# Fallback function does not work solidity

Tags: solidity

Solidity version is 0.5.1
the buyTokens function works fine when i call it directly from myetherwallet or remix, but it does not work when i send some ether to address. I think it doesn't even call the fallback function.

the buyTokens function is an public payable function

```
function () external payable {
        buyTokens(msg.sender);
    }
```

Comment: Fallback functions cannot do that, the gas spent in a function is limited to a very small gas amount

Comment: You can use function buytoken() external payable without the fallback function

Answer (score 1):

A fallback function is invoked when the contract receives some Ether(or a non existent function is called) but the gas provided is only enough so as to emit a event if called using transfer or send . You can use call and specify the amount of gas if you want to execute any function inside the fallback.
You can refer to this link
https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/